# getting most rented movie per category

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have movie rental database that I'm working with here and I am trying to find the most rented movie per category. I want to print out the title and the category. Here is my block of code:

```
declare
type listOfCat is varray(10) of varchar2(10);

categories listOfCat;
movCount number(2);
title varchar2(50);

begin 
  select distinct category bulk collect into categories from movie;

  for i in 1.. categories.count loop
    select max(count) into movCount from 
    (select count(r.movie_id) as count, m.title as mov, m.CATEGORY as cat from rental r
    join movie m on r.movie_id = m.movie_id
    where m.category = categories(i)
    group by m.title, m.CATEGORY
    );

    dbms_output.put_line(movCount || ' ' || categories(i)); 
  end loop;
end;
```

Now the problem is I don't know how to get the movie title in this case. I tried giving max(count) an alias and doing alias.mov but when adding a group by clause at the end, it gives a an invalid identifier error. Also grouping by the result I get at max(count) will just separate the result again if I have several movies per category. Finally, I also tried putting movCount, mov and cat into arrays and display them in parallel but that does not guarantee me the order would be right.

Movie table has movie_id, title, category, qty_available.
Rental table has movie_id, customer_id, due_date, returned
Customer table has customer_id, name

Comment: Any chance you could provide a sample of the data in `movie` and `rental`?

Comment: I wondered what would you like to do in the event of a tie?   For example if the max number of rentals in a category is shared by two movies in that category.

Comment: take the first one

Comment: there added what each table has

Comment: Ok good to know.  And thanks for the extra data. One other question--is PL/SQL a requirement here?  Would a plain SQL query be usable?

Comment: PL/SQL is a must

Comment: Ok thanks for the quick response.  I'll post something up

Comment: Is PL/SQL a must for a specific reason?  Seems like that @alexgibbs answer a is just a wrapper around a a plain SQL query.  If you can do it in SQL alone, it will be faster, and less coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get a `max` or `min` of one attribute and also bring along another field associated with that `max` or `min` is to use `KEEP`.  `KEEP` functions to sort the data by one field, then take the record(s) with the extreme value in that attribute and resolve ties by `max` or `min`.

Here's an example with some tables that should be compatible with the query and tables you provided:

Create the test tables:

```
CREATE TABLE RENTAL(
MOVIE_ID NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE MOVIE(
  MOVIE_ID NUMBER,
  TITLE VARCHAR2(64),
  CATEGORY VARCHAR2(64)
);
```

And load some test data;

```
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES(1,'The Fugitive','Thriller');
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES(2,'No Country for Old Men','Thriller');
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES(3,'The Martian','Sci-Fi');
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES(4,'Back To The Future','Sci-Fi');
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES(5,'Alien','Sci-Fi');


INSERT INTO RENTAL VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO RENTAL VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO RENTAL VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO RENTAL VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO RENTAL VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO RENTAL VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO RENTAL VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO RENTAL VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO RENTAL VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO RENTAL VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO RENTAL VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO RENTAL VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO RENTAL VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO RENTAL VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO RENTAL VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO RENTAL VALUES (2);
```

Now if we query to get some initial expectation for the pl/sql block, we can see we have a tie in the `Thriller` category:

```
SELECT MOVIE.TITLE, MOVIE.CATEGORY, COUNT(*) AS RENTAL_COUNT FROM MOVIE
  INNER JOIN RENTAL
    ON MOVIE.MOVIE_ID = RENTAL.MOVIE_ID
GROUP BY MOVIE.TITLE, MOVIE.CATEGORY
ORDER BY 2 ASC, 3 DESC;

TITLE                   CATEGORY  RENTAL_COUNT  
The Martian             Sci-Fi    4             
Alien                   Sci-Fi    2             
Back To The Future      Sci-Fi    2             
No Country for Old Men  Thriller  4             
The Fugitive            Thriller  4
```

So we should end up with `The Martian` in `Sci-Fi`, but we'll need to resolve that tie in `Thriller` with `KEEP`.

Now run the pl/sql block.  I modified the query and added the movie title to the printed statement here but it is largely the same. max-count gets the higest number of rentals, and `KEEP` gets the movie with that number of rentals.

```
declare
  type listOfCat is varray(10) of varchar2(10);

  categories listOfCat;
  movCount number(2);
  movieTitle varchar2(50);

begin
  select distinct category bulk collect into categories from movie;

  for i in 1.. categories.count loop
    SELECT MIN(TITLE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC),
      MAX(COUNT(*))
    INTO movieTitle, movCount
    FROM MOVIE
      INNER JOIN RENTAL
        ON MOVIE.MOVIE_ID = RENTAL.MOVIE_ID
    WHERE MOVIE.CATEGORY = categories(i)
    GROUP BY MOVIE.TITLE;

    dbms_output.put_line(utl_lms.format_message('Category: %s, Most-Rented-Movie:%s, Rental-Count:%s',categories(i),movieTitle,to_char(movCount)));
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Result:

```
Category: Sci-Fi, Most-Rented-Movie:The Martian, Rental-Count:4
Category: Thriller, Most-Rented-Movie:No Country for Old Men, Rental-Count:4
```

In this case, `MIN(TITLE)` resolved the tie between `The Fugitive` and `No Country for Old Men`.

Comment: now I see so to get any other columns in the max(count) record I use keep